# Can Googlebot crawl reCAPTCHA v2?

Tags: googlebot, captcha

I'm building a website that contains certain forms protected by reCAPTCHA v2.

Can Googlebot crawl content protected by its own reCAPTCHA v2?

Comment: LOL, that would be disaster for reCAPTCHA publicity:  reCAPTCHA so weak that even Googlebot can break it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: I guess OP doesn’t mean breaking, but just "ignoring"/knowing, because Google, as reCAPTCHA hoster, would technically be able to know the CAPTCHA solution.

Comment: @unor even worse ;-) image the public image loss, and this in times of GDPR et al.

Answer (score 2):

No it can't.

The whole purpose of reCAPTCHA is to verify that the connection is being controlled by a human and not a machine. If there is content behind the reCAPTCHA protected form that you want Google to index then you need to identify another way for Google to be able to look at it (like giving Google authentication information to bypass the CAPTCHA) but by and large this would be pointless as any page that is protected by a CAPTCHA shouldn't be accessed by a machine and should only be accessed by a human.

Answer (score 1):

depends... I'm quite sure Googlebot doesn't trigger the challenge if you use invisible reCaptcha. We have file downloads that require generating a download token, and Google successfully generates these tokens constantly. (so it must be bypassing the invisible reCaptcha)